# How can i display tooltiptext on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

My tooltiptext will display when hover on Chrome and others browser, but not for Safari. so I want just want to set visibility as "visible" especially for safari.

I can detect browser but I can't find a way to change visibility of tooltiptext by JavaScript yet.

My tooltiptext css

```
.tlp {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tlp .tooltiptext {
  background-color: #FDF5BF;
  color: #404040;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  top: -225%;
  left: -50%;
}
.tlp:hover .tooltiptext  {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

code for detect browser

```
        let safariAgent = 
            userAgentString.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

        if ((chromeAgent) && (safariAgent)) 
            safariAgent = false;
 document.querySelector(".output-safari").textContent
                    = safariAgent;
```

I tried to replace class but  that not work.

```
if (safariAgent == true){
    $(".sss").toggleClass("ccc");
}
```

class

```
.ccc{
  visibility: visible;
}  
.sss{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

example of how I use tooltiptext

```
<p3><hili class="tlp">Color<p5   class="tooltiptext sss  t2">pink</p5></hili>
```

If there is another method that can give the same result as I want, Please tell me.
Thanks in advance.